# Animation does not contain definition for 'play'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

For no apparent reason Unity has started just now started showing errors in this code such as the attachment picture below.

I cannot get over this error and can't find a single explanation.
Since it seems fairly simple l think there might be some people who can give a hint.

[image: Errormessage1]

[image: Errormessage2]

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animation anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        anim.Play();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own class is called `Animation` .. and no it has no such method ;)

Careful with naming your class equally to an already existing one.

You will now have to use explicitly [`UnityEngine.Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) everywhere

```
public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UnityEngine.Animation anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<UnityEngine.Animation>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        anim.Play();
    }
}
```

since otherwise the compiler will of course assume by `Animation` you are referring to your class itself.

In general: what is the purpose of calling [`Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) **every frame**?